# SharePoint 2013 REST API - Return specific 'likes' for a post in my news feed

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

This is my first question that I have ever posted on here so please be gentle!

I am trying to use a SharePoint 2013 REST service call using JQUERY Ajax to return the total 'likes' the most recent post to a user's SharePoint (MySite) newsfeed has recieved. Basically I have developed a little social webpart for our company intranet that displays the user's portrait and their last post (truncated). I thought it would be cool to also show how many likes that post has recieved but I have not been able to find out how to do so.

Here is a segment of my code which is working but I am only adding it to this question to give some insight to what I am trying to achieve -

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/_api/social.feed/my/feed(MaxThreadCount=1,SortOrder=1)",
  method: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.d.SocialFeed.UnreadMentionCount != null)
   {document.getElementById("unreadmentions").innerHTML = data.d.SocialFeed.UnreadMentionCount;}
   else
   document.getElementById("unreadmentions").innerHTML = 0;

   html = data.d.SocialFeed.Threads.results[0].Actors.results[0].StatusText;

   if (html == null)
   {document.getElementById("socialstatus").innerHTML = "No posts available";}
   else
   {
     html = html.substring(0,30) + " ...";
     document.getElementById("socialstatus").innerHTML = html;          
   }
}, error: function (data) {}
```

For the life of me I can not understand why that particular feed does not also return how many likes that post has recieved. Seems kind of silly that it wouldnt.

Cheers for the help!